# Mercurial - Could not lock working directory

Tags: deployment, mercurial

We have a web-app, that we're deploying to a remote Ubuntu server.

The app is stored on BitBucket, and we also have Fabric scripts we're using to automatically deploy the app.

On the server, we have the files for the app in /var/www/name_of_site, this folder being a  Mercurial repository. The files are owned by the user www-data, group www-data, and are group-writable.

When I attempt to login to the server and do a "hg add" inside the repository, I get a:

```
adding fabfiles/fabfile.py
abort: could not lock working directory of /var/www/site_name: Permission denied
```

I tried adding myself to www-data, and it still gives that error message. I'm able to create folders/files inside /var/www/site_name fine.

Have I set things up incorrectly here? Should the permissions be different?

Cheers,
Victor

Comment: check if you can add/remove files inside the .hg directory

Comment: Well, that was a bit silly. Tonfa, you're right. Haha,  permissions on the .hg directory were wrong.

The error messages all referred to not being able to lock the working directory, /var/www/site_name, so I kept trying to muck around with the permissions with that. I didn't realise it was because my .hg directory was created with another user.

Anyhow, all fixed now =). Thanks again.

Comment: Maybe you want to upvote tonfa comment, translate the comment into an anser and accept the answer :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Check if you can add/remove files inside the .hg directory – tonfa Oct 27 at 10:27

Comment: Moved tonfa's answer from a comment to an answer (and made it community wiki so I'm not point whoring).

Comment: In Linux you need to log back out and log back in for any changes in your user's group memberships to take effect.

My mercurial repo and dir were owned by a group I was not a member of. I added myself to the group and chowned all directories 775 (so I could edit stuff). However "touch x.txt" was not working in the directory ... until I logged out and logged back in.